# What are the differences between db2 and mysql?

Tags: mysql, db2

Can somebody please let me know what are the major differences between IBM's DB2 and Oracles MySql?like performance wise, backup, data encryption, cost etc? pros and cons too?. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem in the question. This might be OT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

db-engines.com compare different relational dbs. I hope [this](http://db-engines.com/en/system/DB2%3BMicrosoft+SQL+Server%3BMySQL%3BOracle) helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this question several times:

- [MySQL vs DB2 RDBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299127/mysql-vs-db2-rdbms/9302210#9302210)
- [MySQL vs DB2 Express-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533795/mysql-vs-db2-express-c/4534691#4534691)

Even though, you are asking about performance, backup, etc., and these are not question for StackOverFlow, because they are not related to programming.

As @Kamal said, please visit db-engines that is becoming the tool to compare rdbms.